# JS form validation. Check if field(s) exist if so execute function(s) if it returns true than submit the form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I have a function that get passed the formDOM element. It check if the field exist via data attribute. For example: `data-validate-email` If that is the case it needs to be validated with the corresponding function for example `emailIsValid()` .

The functions all return a **boolean** with `true` or `false`. How can i manage/track if one of the functions return false so i can prevent the form from submitting. A global variable doesn't work because it get overwritten by the next function.

```
onSubmit(form, event)
{
    event.preventDefault();

    const fields = form.querySelectorAll( `[${textValidation}]`);
    const passwordField = form.querySelector(`[${passwordValidation}]`);
    const repeatPasswordField = form.querySelector(`[${passwordRepeatValidation}]`);
    const email = form.querySelector(`[${emailValidation}]`);

    if(fields)
    {
        this.TextIsValid(fields);
    }

    if(email)
    {
        this.emailIsValid(email);
    }

    if(passwordField)
    {
        this.passwordStrengthIsValid(passwordField);
    }

    if(repeatPasswordField)
    {
        this.passwordMatches(passwordField, repeatPasswordField);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked into HTML5 form validation? Alot of these things are now built-in, providing your validation rules can be expressed with these. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation

Comment: I am use some of the HTML5 validation but with email for example it only check if you do `foo@bar` so it doens't check the postfix

Comment: Even if you provide a regexp pattern to check against?

Answer (score 0):

With your current solution something like this would work:

```js
onSubmit(form, event)
{
    event.preventDefault();

    const fields = form.querySelectorAll( `[${textValidation}]`);
    const passwordField = form.querySelector(`[${passwordValidation}]`);
    const repeatPasswordField = form.querySelector(`[${passwordRepeatValidation}]`);
    const email = form.querySelector(`[${emailValidation}]`);
    const isValid = true;

    if(fields && !this.TextIsValid(fields))
    {
        isValid = false;
    }

    if(email && !this.emailIsValid(email);)
    {
        isValid = false;
    }
    // And so on...
}
```

This way your "global" `isValid` variable will not be overridden to true if one of the validation passes. It can only be assigned false when a validation does NOT pass.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a global variable `finalStatus` in combination with the logical operator `&&`

```
onSubmit(form, event)
{
    event.preventDefault();

    let isValid = true;

    const fields = form.querySelectorAll( `[${textValidation}]`);
    const passwordField = form.querySelector(`[${passwordValidation}]`);
    const repeatPasswordField = form.querySelector(`[${passwordRepeatValidation}]`);
    const email = form.querySelector(`[${emailValidation}]`);

    if(fields)
    {
        isValid = isValid && this.TextIsValid(fields);
    }

    if(email)
    {
        isValid= isValid && this.emailIsValid(email);
    }

    if(passwordField)
    {
        isValid= isValid && this.passwordStrengthIsValid(passwordField);
    }

    if(repeatPasswordField)
    {
        isValid= isValid && this.passwordMatches(passwordField, repeatPasswordField);
    }

    console.log(isValid)
}
```

You could even shorten the process by checking the status of `finalStatus` in your `if` to avoid entering in if the status is already `false`

```
if(isValid && email)
```

Comment: @Marc, could you please describe why it doesn't work ?

Comment: I am wrong with saying it doesn't work but with this concept. If one of the validation functions returns false. It won't check the other fields anymore, because of `isValid && .....` This means it won't throw an error message to the user. You want the user to notify with user with warnings/errors for each field

Comment: @Marc It won't check the other fields if you put `isValid` inside your `if` as explained in the last part of my answer. Just remove it from your `if` as it is in the first part of the answer

Comment: the problem is not inside the if. `isValid = isValid && this.TextIsValid(fields);` if this returns false it will never execute the function because in the next && operatator `isValid` is false. If you remove isValid, the function will overwrite the value. So if 4 are false and the last one is true. It says it is valid but that is not the case.

Comment: @Marc then do it in the opposite : `this.textIsValid(fields) && isValid`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Array` and `filter` to solve this.

```
onSubmit(form, event);
{
  event.preventDefault();
  let validation = [];

  const fields = form.querySelectorAll(`[${textValidation}]`);
  const passwordField = form.querySelector(`[${passwordValidation}]`);
  const repeatPasswordField = form.querySelector(
    `[${passwordRepeatValidation}]`
  );
  const email = form.querySelector(`[${emailValidation}]`);

  if (fields) {
    validation.push(this.TextIsValid(fields));
  }

  if (email) {
    validation.push(this.emailIsValid(email));
  }

  if (passwordField) {
    validation.push(this.passwordStrengthIsValid(passwordField));
  }

  if (repeatPasswordField) {
    validation.push(this.passwordMatches(passwordField, repeatPasswordField));
  }

  // Filter the array with false value and then check the array length. 
  let validationStatus  = validation.filter(item => !item);
  if(validationStatus.length === 0) {
    //submit your form
  }
}
```